# One method for two different signatures

Tags: c#

I have two methods which do exactly the same, but one accepts a `PaintEventArgs` class parameter while the other accepts a `PrintPageEventArgs` class parameter. This forces me to write two different methods which tends to be a little excessive for such a slight difference.

```
public static void DoAllTasks_Panel(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Commands...
}

public static void DoAllTasks_Print(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Commands...
}
```

I have tried to merge them into a single method using an `EventArgs` class parameter with no success, as follows:

```
public static void DoAllTasks(EventArgs e)
{
    // Commands...
}
```

Is there any possibility to merge them into a single method?

Comment: "with no success":  what exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `DoAllTasks_Panel` and `DoAllTasks_Print` genuinely do the same thing, and only exist because of the need for two different signatures, then the standard approach is to create a third, private, method that does the work and have each call it:

```
public static void DoAllTasks_Panel(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DoCommands();
}

public static void DoAllTasks_Print(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    DoCommands();
}

private static DoCommands()
{
    // Commands...
}
```

This way you are separating concerns and satisfying DRY (do not repeat yourself) principles nicely: you have individual event handler methods and a third method that does all the common work.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a third `private` method that takes the values you care about from those EventArgs as parameters, and then make those two methods one-liners that just call the third method.

Comment: Can anybody provide some sample code to illustrate this approach? This would help me a lot.

Comment: @Cebri, please see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As [Actorclavilis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514672/actorclavilis) mentioned - lets assume you need to access the **graphics** member common to both parameters :

create a method

```
private void useGraphics (System.Drawing.Graphics g)
{
    g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\\My Folder\\MyFile.bmp"), ev.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds);
}
```

then call as follows :

```
public static void DoAllTasks_Panel(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    useGraphics (e.graphics)    
}

public static void DoAllTasks(EventArgs e)
{
    useGraphics (e.graphics)    
}
```